# ZSH shell setting up paths

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh

I'm trying to install and set up the following program on my Mac Big Sur.
https://bondxray.org/software/aline.html

I unpacked it on /Applications. However, my knowledge is quite limited and I can't figure out how to set it up for a zsh shell. I can't find the .zshrc file so I can add lines to it and set up the software for its use.

Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: The .zshrc is not something you can **find** someone. It is the file which holds your customizations for an interactive zsh. Therefore you have to create it if you want to do customizations.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed it into `/Applications/aline`:

- Open Terminal
- Run `echo 'ALINEHOME=/Applications/aline; export ALINEHOME' >> ~/.zshrc`
- Run `echo 'PATH=$ALINEHOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH' >> ~/.zshrc`
- Open a new Terminal tab and run `echo $PATH` to check whether the path is set correctly
- Run `aline`

PS: The page you link seems to be rather old, so I wouldn't be surprised if some of the prerequisites are not fullfilled any more in recent versions of macOS.

Comment: Did BigSur do away with the `.app` extension for applications? i.e. ALINEHOME is not `/Applications/aline.app`?  My MBP 2012 will never know BigSur, so this is interesting to me.

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast reply and useful comments!
I was able to create the path as you mentioned. I now have another error that I believe is due to my new macOS version, as you indicated. 

thanks again.

Comment: Yes, it isn't an app. I decided to use Applications as it is where I install all the programs

Comment: thanks a lot! Yes, I will give it a try as I think the new issue has to do with the path to the library. If I can't figure it out. I will create another question

Comment: Ah, sorry for butting in with confusion. (I was hoping something cool happened in Big Sur! :-)

Comment: Using a bunch of `echo` commands to create a text file a bit odd in modern times. Last time I have seen something like this must have been in the early 1970s on Data General minicomputers. Even the early Unix machines already offered some (crude) **text editor**, and this is usually the type of program we use today when manually creating a file. From the command line, you can start a simple editor on macos using i.e. `nano FILENAME`.

Comment: Maybe, but isn't it easier (and less dangerous) to copy and paste a few lines into a text editor?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this issue is resolved but here are a couple general tips and an alternate method.

---

On modern MacOS versions, while in Finder, the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>. period</kbd> will toggle the display of invisible files.

The `zsh` config file `.zshrc`, starting with a period, will be invisible by default, and if configuration of the shell is unchanged will be found in the user's home directory. `/Users/your-name`. From the terminal it is always possible to type `open ~` to access the home folder in Finder.

The other answer provides a programmatic way to add to the PATH. It creates the intermediate environment variable `ALINEHOME` which can be useful for concision and separation.

This variable referencing where the `aline` program resides is appended to `.zshrc` with the part of the commands `>> ~/.zshrc`.

---

Next, what is the `PATH` and why is it involved here?

> The Unix PATH is an environment variable that tells the shell which directories it should look for when you issue commands. You can think of it like a list of Application or Program Files folders. ([source](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/what-is-the-unix-path-and-how-do-you-add-programs-to-it/#:%7E:text=The%20Unix%20PATH%20is%20an,Application%20or%20Program%20Files%20folders.))

Numerous commands/programs can be run from the terminal by default. For example, the `open` command itself. Nothing needs to be configured to run `open` just by referencing its name from any terminal.

The executable file for `open` is contained in the folder `/usr/bin` among many other programs.

[image: Finder window open to /usr/bin]

Since an environmental variable like `PATH` is accessible any any time—throughout the entire environment—the shell always knows to have commands like `open` on deck because *`/usr/bin` is on the PATH*.

[image: The shell results of echo $path with /usr/bin highlighted]

---

An additional method for 'installing' the program in question. Reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18077919);

`zsh`, "Z-shell", in particular allows for a more readable syntax to add to the PATH.

```sh
path+=(/Applications/aline)
```

`aline` will become available anywhere (next time you load up a shell/open the terminal).

Or, if for example `aline` was in a subdirectory `/Applications/programs`,

```sh
path+=(/Applications/programs)
```

`aline` will be available along with anything else in that subdirectory.

`+` is the operative. Setting any variable like `a=1` would replace its previous contents. The preexisting elements are important to retain on the PATH so the syntax `+=` is a handy way to append instead of reset.

These lines, `path+=(...)`, would be added to the `.zshrc` file in the same way. You could add the lines programmatically with the other method mentioned, or open the file in a text editor and type them manually. A foolproof way to open the file with TextEdit is by typing `open -e ~/.zshrc`.